# GET Azure ADusers through powershell

Tags: .net, powershell, active-directory, azure-active-directory, azure-powershell

I am able to get the AD users in a C# console application, but I'm not able to get the AD users with powershell.
Below is the C# code:

```cs
string responseString = null;
using (var client=new HttpClient())
{
    var data = new Dictionary<string, string>
    {
        { "grant_type", "password" },
        { "client_id", "client_id" },
        { "client_secret", "client_secret" },
        { "scope", "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" },
        { "userName", Your username here },
        { "password", Your password here }
    };
    var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(data);
    var response = await client.PostAsync("https://login.microsoftonline.com/id/oauth2/v2.0/token", content);
    responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
}
var token= JsonSerializer.Deserialize<TokenClass>(responseString);
            
var graphapistring = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/";
using (var client1 = new HttpClient())
{
    client1.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token.access_token);

    var response = await client1.GetAsync(graphapistring);
    responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
}
var user= JsonSerializer.Deserialize<userdetails>(responseString);
```

I need help converting the above code into powershell.

Comment: Hi, please refer to the solution I provided below. If it helps your problem, please [accept](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) it as answer(click on the check mark beside my answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in). Thanks in advance~

Comment: If still have any problem, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

For your requirement, you just need to use **AzureAD** module in powershell.

Install **AzureAD** module by running this command in powershell: `Install-Module AzureAD`. You can refer to this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/active-directory/install-adv2?view=azureadps-2.0#installing-the-azure-ad-module).

After install the module, we need to connect to azure ad first. Run `Connect-AzureAD` command to connect.

Then you can get the AD users by running [Get-AzureADUser](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azuread/get-azureaduser?view=azureadps-2.0) command, this command can just response a few fields of each user. If you want more fields of each user, you can run `Get-AzureADUser | fl`